# How do I convert int array to string array. And get my "input" value to the PointsTabToPlace (String input) code?

Tags: java

How do I get my "input" value to the "PointsTabToPlace" method code?
Maybe I need to change my code like the other method? (input. XXX)
My problem is getting the "input" value to the main class from "PointsTabToPlace".
The code works, When I debuging the code not convert from int-array to string array correctly its "blank".
But how do I get the "input" value into the code in the PointsTabToPlace method?

```
public class Points {

    private int[] pointsTab = { 60, 54, 48, 43, 40, 38, 36, 34, 32, 31, 30, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 
                                20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9,  8,  7,  6,  5,  4,  3,  2,  1 };
    private String[] place = { "1", "2",  "3",  "4",  "5",  "6",  "7",  "8",  "9",  "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", 
                              "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40" };

    public String PointsTabToPlace(String input) {
        // Points till place
        int[] strArray = new int [pointsTab.length];
        String str = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++) {
            for (int index = 0; index < pointsTab.length; index++) {
                if (pointsTab[index] == strArray[i]) {
                    //strArray[i] = String.valueOf(pointsTab[i]);
                    str = str + place[index] + "";
                }
            }
        }
        return str;
    }

    public String PlaceToPointsTab(String input) {

        // Place till points
        String[] array = input.split(" ");
        String ints = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int index = 0; index < place.length; index++) {
                if (place[index].equals(array[i])) {
                    ints = ints + pointsTab[index] + " ";
                }
            }
        }
        return ints;
    }
}

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

public class MainSkidskytte extends Points{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Points translator = new Points();       
        System.out.println("Du har 3 alternativ:");
        System.out.println("1. Översätta poäng till placering.\n2. Omvandla placcering till poäng. \n3. Avsluta programet! ");
        int choice = Integer.valueOf(sc.nextLine());
        switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("--> 1. Skriv en placering (1-40) som omvandlas till poäng: (Använd mellanslag mellan orden)");
            String input = sc.nextLine();
            String result = translator.PointsTabToPlace(input);
            System.out.println("--> Omvandling till poäng blir: \n" + result);
            
            break;
                    
        case 2:
            System.out.println("--> 2. Skriv poäng: (Ha mellanslag mellan varje \"bokstav\") (använd | för mellanrum mellan orden.)");
            input = sc.nextLine();
            result = translator.PlaceToPointsTab(input);
            System.out.println("--> Översättning till placering blir:\n" + result);
            break;
            
        case 3:
            System.out.println("Programmet avslutas");
            break;
            
        default:
            System.err.println("\n***FELMEDDELANDE! FEL SIFFRA! (VÄLJ 1 2 3)***");
            sc.next();
        }
        sc.close(); // close scanner
        System.exit(0);
    }

}
```

Comment: What input values? Where do these input values come from?

Comment: I update the code with my "mainclass" if it is clearer what I mean now? As you can see in the "PlaceToPointsTab" method, I have a " String [] array = input.split (" "); " I think I need some similar "input" to make contact with the main class ??

Comment: your code is already doing what you ask for via `String result = translator.PointsTabToPlace(input);`

Comment: @Bohemian I think I need some similar "input" to get in touch with the main class ?? Because the print is "blank" when I print out "result" in "case: 1" in the main class.

Comment: When I type "60" it should be "1" but it will only be "blank"?